# Python fill list with integers, can't stop loop with 'exit'

Tags: python, list, mean

I'm trying to make an empty list that the user will fill up with random integers, until the user writes 'exit', and then the program should calculate the mean of the integers (I'm supposed to do this without the help from Python modules or functions like `len()`). I have my code this far:

```
# Start with an empty list.
numbers = []

# Set new_number to something other than 'exit'.
new_number = ''

# Start a loop that will run until the user enters 'exit'.
while new_number != 'exit':
    new_number = int(input("Write a new number to the list, or enter 'exit': "))

# Add the new number to our list.
    if new_number != 'exit':
       numbers.append(new_number)

# Start calculating the mean of the numbers.
def average(numbers):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for num in numbers:
        total += num
        count += 1

    return total / count

Numbmean = average(numbers)

print( 'The mean: ' + round(Numbmean ,2))
```

However, I'm presented with either two of the following:

1. Either the program doesn't like that I'm trying to specify 'exit' as an integer, (`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'exit'`) or:
2. The program can't calculate the mean of string variables, because input will become a string (`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'`).

How would I solve this?

Comment: Convert the number to an integer before adding it to the list of numbers.

Comment: `numbers.append(int(new_number))`

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Didn't realize you could specify it that way. And now I see what you mean with your other comment... sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is caused by following line:

```
new_number = int(input("Write a new number to the list, or enter 'exit': "))
```

If user types `exit` then input returns it and naturally it can't be converted to integer which causes the `ValueError`. You can fix this by first checking if the `input` return value matches with `exit` and breaking the loop if it does. After the check you can convert the return value to int and append it to the list.

```
# Start a loop that will run until the user enters 'exit'.
while True:
    new_number = input("Write a new number to the list, or enter 'exit': ")

    # Add the new number to our list.
    if new_number == 'exit':
        break

    try:
        numbers.append(int(new_number))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter number or exit')
```

This should also fix the second error you were having since it ensures that all items in `numbers` are integers.

Comment: u can do `new_number = input("something")` and than `numbers.append(int(new_number))`. But for conversion should u use `try...catch...`

Comment: yes, this code does not "it ensures that all items in numbers are integers.", no it breaks if you enter anything besides an integer or 'exit' (e.g. 'exit ' with whitespace). You have to use try to ensure that

Comment: Added error handling to make it complete and removed the remark of code not handling other inputs beside integers and `exit`